# html 5 flash/animate custom font

Tags: javascript, css, html, flash, fonts

I am creating my very first Animate(flash) CC banner in HTML5/canvas.

The problem I'm having is that I want to add a custom font. My thoughts were to add them with `@font-face`.

This seemed to be working in the CC (2015) version, but I got an update to version 2015.1 and now I can add a `@font-face` to my html file but I can't define the fontname to the js file. I am able to use typekit but the font isn't on the typekit :-(

Maybe one of you can see where to put the fontname.
Here is a content part of the js file.

```
// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    width: 120,
    height: 600,
    fps: 25,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    webfonts: {},
    manifest: []
};



lib.webfontAvailable = function(family) { 
    lib.properties.webfonts[family] = true;
    var txtFilters = lib.webFontTxtFilters && lib.webFontTxtFilters[family] || [];
    for(var f = 0; f < txtFilters.length; ++f) {
        txtFilters[f].updateCache();
    }
};
```

Publish settings font:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is a programming problem, it looks more like a question about how to do a thing in the new version of Adobe's Animate CC that you could do in an older version, in which case you should probably be asking how to do this over on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) or even just the [adobe forum for Animate CC](https://forums.adobe.com/community/animate), which would be the first obvious place for this question.

Comment: Well I checked at the Adobe forum but no luck there. After some Googleing I found that this has to be added programmatically. So that is why I came here.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I found worked for me (using Animate CC 2017.5):

1. Create a new text element using the Text tool (T)
2. Change the properties to Dynamic Text:
   [Text tool properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvu6q.png)
3. Change the text to your desired font.
4. File > Publish
5. Open up the published .html and .js files.
6. Add @font-face css to html file head as you would normally (change the font's src accordingly). You can also add more than one:

```html
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: MyCustomFont;
    src: url("assets/mycustomfont.woff");
  }
</style>
<!-- write your code here -->
```

7. Find your text element inside the .js file and edit it to your liking:

```js
this.text = new cjs.Text("My dynamically changing text", "46px 'MyCustomFont'");
```

8. Done! Your text should now render properly with your custom font.